# Ubuntu Software Frozen Page Problem

Tags: software-center

Whenever I open software center this page appears,It seems it has frozen in this page.

[image]

Comment: and It even doen't change by clicking back,It is completely frozen as an Image

Comment: Can you completely close (aka kill) the software center, and restart it? Is it still the same? I'm not sure what it's name is, but `pkill [name]` after verifying with `pgrep [name]` might work, or `ps auxf` and browse to see if anything looks "right")

Comment: Yes I can close Ubuntu software but when I open it again it is frozen like the above picture

Comment: Hmmm... if the process is being killed, and it's still starting up corrupted, maybe it has some config files, or cache or temp files that should be reset/deleted